# How high is a baseball after 5 seconds of being thrown off of a 175 foot building? And how many seconds does it take to hit the ground?

Tags: quadratic-forms

A person standing close to the edge on the top of a 175-foot building throws a baseball vertically upward. The quadratic equation

$$h = -16 t^2 + 160 t + 175$$

models the ball's height, $h$ , above the ground in feet, $t$ seconds after it was thrown.

1. How high is the baseball after five seconds?
2. How many seconds does it take until the ball finally hits the ground? Round to the nearest tenth of a second.

Comment: It seems likely that you can make progress on at least one of the questions. If you indicate what you have done, and what you have trouble with, that will make it easier for people to give you relevant help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS:

(1) Evaluate $$h(5) = -16(5)^2 + 160(5) + 175$$ I.e. Plug into the formula the number $5$ and calculate $h(5)$: the height of the ball five seconds after it was thrown.

(2) Solve for $t$ when $h(t) = 0$. That is, find the zeros of $$h = -16t^2 + 160 t + 175 =  16t^2 - 160 t - 175 = 0$$ Try to *factor* to find the zeros of the equation, or else use the *quadratic formula* to find the zeros: what values of $t$ make $h$ equal zero? Which value is positive? That's the time in seconds from when the ball was thrown until when the ball hits the ground. You may hover over the solution below to check your answer:

> $$t = 5 + \dfrac{5\sqrt {23}}{4} \approx \;11\;\;\text{seconds}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I really wish I didn't have to ask you anything else but I haven't taken a math class in nearly three years. What would be the first step for (2)? Does factoring mean 'foiling'?

Comment: Actually, I'd use the quadratic formula here; it doesn't seem to factor nicely into integers. Do you remember the quadratic formula? $$t = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ In your case, $a = 16, \;b = -160, \; c = -175$

Comment: Ah, yes! I was just reminded of the formula last night with a tutor. I got 11 seconds, and that seems to be right! Very cool. Alright, see, I always overestimate how hard these problems all. Gotta keep a cool head. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes indeed, don't get "psyched out" by word problems. You know all you need to know to do such a problem!

Comment: @amWhy: I like that you are always helpful, understanding and provide good advice! +1